# When writing cover letters and reference letters, is it better to have no addressing or wrong addressing?

Tags: cover-letter

When applying for a company, I have found that it was quite chaotic in terms of getting the right person to address as well as the right physical address. I am wondering what is worse between no addressing at all (using To Whom It May Concern, etc.) or getting the wrong address (using whichever first name you find, recruiting manager, or head of a department).

Comment: Joe has the right answer. Call and ask. I know it's hard, but people do it all the time and it is the most effective method by far.

Comment: It probably depends a bit on whether you're emailing or sending physical letters - it's easy for a wrongly addressed email to disappear entirely, or fall into a mailbox that is never checked.

Answer (score 2):

Recruiter here :)
I would advise going with no addressing at all. It is hard to find information regarding who is the hiring manager. Recruiters are often the first ones to read applications (cover letters included). If you found the job on LinkedIn, sometimes the advertisement shows the responsible person hiring for that job, and, if this is the case, feel free to contact them directly on LinkedIn.
Also, make sure that you are only sending cover letters when specifically requested - they are not that popular anymore. Instead, focus your energy on your resume and show your results, that will go further than any cover letter :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't sweat it.

If you go through all the steps of the hiring process 10 or mote people will read the cover letter. Most of those people will not be the addressee.

If you know the name, then use the name. Otherwise "to whom it may concern." is fine.